# URL works when pasted/entered in IE9 address bar, but not in href or window.open

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, filesystems, internet-explorer-9, intranet

Context: this is part of an INTRANET system, requiring basic authentication and running off an internally facing server accessible only within our work domain.

So, the situation is that IE9 will follow links to network files & folders, via mapped drives without any problem. I've got this working fine, a kind of IE only security exploit which works perfect for our situation and many others :)

For example: 
`<a href="file:///U:/foo/bar.txt" target=\"_new\">Example</a>`works fine.
Now, **the problem is that** `<a href="file:///C:/foo/bar.txt" target=\"_new\">Example</a>` **won't work**.

However *if I copy and paste* `file:///C:/foo/bar.txt` *into the address bar, it loads fine.* And same goes for local folders.

Another point to note is that I've tried with `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/foo/bar.txt');">Example</a>`and experienced the exact same results. URLs pointing to files & folders on network mapped drives work fine, C:\ folders & files don't work (unless pasted into address bar).

So my questions are:

1. considering I have a valid URL, why won't IE9 follow it when clicked, but will follow it when entered into the address bar?

2. Why does IE have no qualms about launching network files & folders, but not local ones?

3. How can I get this working? (and I have no hesitation to use any dirty IE hack necessary)

An answer to any 1 of these questions would be great, but gold star goes to the person who can answer #3!

I'm suspecting/hoping it's simply an obscure security setting somewhere which my googling hasn't been able to unearth.

Thanks for your time & hope this rings a bell with someone who has experienced & solved this issue before :)

edit: I've just noticed that IE9 is re-interpreting my links!! If I view source code and see: `<a href="C:/foo/bar.txt" target="_new">Example</a>` or `<a href="file://C:/foo/bar.txt" target="_new">Example</a>`, when I hover over the link, or copy the shortcut, I get `file:///C:/foo/bar.txt`. So I think I'm fighting an uphill battle with trying to form the "correct" URL. I'm sure this is not a code-syntax error, but a setting somewhere to enable these C: links to be followed.

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo or not, but you are using `U:/` drive on the working example, and `C:/` drive on the non-working drive.

Comment: correct, `U:/` is simply an example of a mapped network drive. I have successfully used several mapped drives, but `C:/` URLs won't work unless entered (typed or pasted) into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to replicate your issue.  I'm able to open up pages in both Chrome and IE using both:

```
<a href="file:///C:/temp/test.py">Example</a>
```

and:

```
<a href="file://C:/temp/test.py">Example</a>
```

Comment: IE9? I will try with `file://c:` instead of `file:///c:/` and see if it makes a difference.